# Bind data from pagination to filter in Angular

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, filter, pagination

I have a simple pagination with letters:

```
<div ng-controller="DataController">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li ng-repeat="letter in data_letters">
      <a href="#" ng-click="setLetter(letter)">{{letter}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>State</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="person in persons | startsWithLetter:letter">
        <td>{{person.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.State}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

What is the easiest way to bind the letter (on which we clicked at the paginaton) to the table filter.
Here is a fully functional plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Trr5LzrcMfZqonD0jvjX?p=preview

I have everything implemented already. It is just the data-binding which is missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue with your code is that you are unnecessarily injecting $scope into your filter:

```
app.filter('startsWithLetter', function($scope) {
```

should be

```
app.filter('startsWithLetter', function() {
```

The other issue is using 'C-D' as a filter value.  I would change $scope.data_letters to be an array of objects that contain a key/value pair like this:

```
$scope.data_letters = [{
  key: 'A',
  value: "A"
}, {
  key: "B",
  value: "B"
}, {
  key: ['C', 'D'],
  value: "C-D"
}];
```

Then change your check in the filter to evaluate all keys, like this:

```
  angular.forEach(letters, function(letter, key) {
    if (itemName.startsWith(letter)) {
      filtered.push(items[i]);
    }
  });
```

You can see it working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7KkNAFUbOoviW1ELrhPz?p=preview) where I forked your plunk.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/50tQuUyNUuEE64rohJlc?p=preview)

Problem was that your filter was not recognized by angular.
Also, I would suggest using

> Chrome Developer Tools

it shows useful debug information

```
app.filter('startsWithLetter', function() {

  console.log("Inside startsWithLetter");
  return function(items, letter) {

   console.log("Inside Filter: Starts with " + letter);
    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var itemName = items[i].Name;

      if (itemName.startsWith(letter)) {
        filtered.push(items[i]);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  };
});
```